# How to write CASE Statement for new column for multiple values in other column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, window-functions

I am writing a T-SQL code to create a new column based on condition of values in other column.

Understand it with example:
I have a table named [dbo].[tr] and values in this table are below -

[image]

Next, in `col1`, I have IDs and in `col2`, I have values. For some IDs, I have multiple values and for some IDs I have single values (either 'X' or '' *(Empty string)* ).

I want to create a new column *(Using CASE Statement)* based on the below conditions:

1. If value in `col2` is 'X' then 'Closed'
2. If value in `col2` is '' then 'Open' *( '' means Empty string)*
3. And if a ID have more than on one value, And for that ID if at least value in `col2` is '' *(Empty String)* then it is 'Open'

Right answer is attached below

[image]

Comment: <pedantry> [`Case`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an _expression_, not a _statement_, in T-SQL. </pedantry>

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this dataset, you can use window functions:

```
select col1, col2,
    min(col2) over(partition by col1) open_closed
from tr
```

This works because, string-wise, `'' < 'X'` - so computing the `min` of `col2` across rows having the same `col1` value is good enough.

A more generic approach, that does not depend on a string sort, would use a `case` expression:

```
select col1, col2,
    max(case when col2 = '' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by col1) as is_open
from tr
```

I find that `1`/`0` values are more appropriate that open/close strings - but you can change that:

```
select col1, col2,
    case when max(case when col2 = '' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by col1) = 1
        then 'open' else 'closed' end as is_open
from tr
```

Or, using the fact that `'open' > 'closed'`

```
select col1, col2,
    max(case when col2 = '' then 'open' else 'closed' end) 
        over(partition by col1) open_closed
from tr
```

Comment: I'd advise applying the scalar expression after the window function, rather than before/inside it. Partly as it reduces the compute overhead (one scalar expression per group, rather than per row), but mostly as it allows indexes to be used in answering the min/max window functions (which the scalar expression would obfuscate).

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE MIN(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1)
  WHEN '' THEN 'OPEN'
          ELSE 'CLOSED'
END
```